# DOCKER_BUILDKIT - passing a token secret during build time from github actions

Tags: python, docker, pip, github-actions

I have a pip installable package that was published using [twine](https://pypi.org/project/twine/) to Azure DevOps artifact.

In my build image I need to download that package and install it with `pip`. So I need to
authenticate against azure artifacts to get it. So I am using [artifacts-keyring](https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-keyring) to do so

The pip installable URL is something like this:

```
https://<token>@pkgs.dev.azure.com/<org>/<project>/_packaging/<feed>/pypi/simple/ --no-cache-dir <package-name>
```

I am trying to use [Docker BuildKit](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#new-docker-build-secret-information) to pass the token during build time.
I am mounting the secret and using it by getting its value with `cat` command substitution:

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1.2

ENV ARTIFACTS_KEYRING_NONINTERACTIVE_MODE=true

RUN --mount=type=secret,id=azdevopstoken,dst=/run/secrets/azdevopstoken \
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install pyyaml numpy lxml artifacts-keyring && \
    echo pip install -i https://"$(cat /run/secrets/azdevopstoken)"@pkgs.dev.azure.com/org>/<project>/_packaging/feed/pypi/simple/ --no-cache-dir package-name
```

and it works locally from my workstation when I run:
(My src file where the token is in plain text is `azdevopstoken.txt` within my local directory structure project)

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker image build --secret id=azdevopstoken,src=./azdevopstoken.txt --progress plain  . -t my-image:tag
```

Now I am running this build command from GitHub actions pipeline
And I got this output:

```
Scould not parse secrets: [id=azdevopstoken,src=./azdevopstoken.txt]: failed to stat ./azdevopstoken.txt: stat ./azdevopstoken.txt: no such file or directory
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

This is expected from me, since I am not uploading `azdevopstoken.txt` file, because I don’t want to have it in my repository, since there is my token in plain text.

Reading carefully [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets#limits-for-secrets), I see there is a workaround to encrypt secrets, perhaps this could be a good solution to implement buildkit from my github actions pipeline, but I think this is an additional step in my workflow, so I am not sure whether follow this option or not.
Foremost because I already passing the secret in the old way by using the `--build-arg` flag during build time of this way:

```
ARG AZ_DEVOPS_TOKEN
ENV AZ_DEVOPS_TOKEN=$AZ_DEVOPS_TOKEN
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install pyyaml numpy lxml artifacts-keyring && \
    pip install -i https://$AZ_DEVOPS_TOKEN@pkgs.dev.azure.com/ORG/PROJECT/_packaging/feed/pypi/simple/ --no-cache-dir PACKAGE-NAME
```

Being my docker build command from GitHub actions of this way:

```
docker image build --build-arg AZ_DEVOPS_TOKEN="${{ secrets.AZ_DEVOPS_TOKEN }}"  . -t containerregistry.azurecr.io/my-image:preview
```

It works perfect, the thing is, I heard `--build-arg` is not a safe solution to pass sensitive information. Despite that I ran `docker history` after this command, and I couldn't see the secret exposed or something similar.

```
> docker history af-fem-uploader:preview-buildarg
IMAGE          CREATED          CREATED BY                                      SIZE      COMMENT
2eff105408c9   34 seconds ago   RUN /bin/sh -c pip install pytest && pytest …   5MB       buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      38 seconds ago   WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot/HttpUploadTrigger/   0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      38 seconds ago   ADD . /home/site/wwwroot # buildkit             1.9MB     buildkit.dockerfile.v0
```

So what is the benefit to pass the secrets via BUILDKIT in order to don’t expose them if I have to upload the file which contains the secret to my repository?

Perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: `--secrets` will ensure you don't leak the information when somebody writes `docker history`.  But I agree, I could have achieved the same by using a `multi-stage` build [ which is a requirement for `docker-compose` as that does not yet support the `--secret` flag ].

Comment: @user13142267 if you're not using docker multi-stage builds and plainly pass your token with `--build-arg` flag, you are going to expose your token in final docker image. You can read more about it here: https://www.alexandraulsh.com/2018/06/25/docker-npmrc-security/